# Solve Differential equation system

Tags: differential-equations

I've tried to solve this differential equation system, buy without any luck.

[image]

This is my code:

```
RSolve[{x'[t] == x[t] - y[t], y'[t] == 5 x[t] - 3 y[t], x[0] == 1, y[0] == 2}, {x[t],
y[t]}, t]
```

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: You should use `DSolve`. `RSolve` is not for differential equations.

Comment: Right. `RSolve[]` is for **difference** equations; `DSolve[]` is for **differential** equations. A matter of continuous versus discrete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend using math: $\ \ \ \dot x=Ax\ \Rightarrow\ x=\text{e}^{At}\ x_0$

```
 A = {{1, -1}, {5, -3}};
 MatrixExp[A t].{1, 2}   //FullSimplify
```

gives: $\ \ \ x_1=\text{e}^{-t}\cos{t},\ \ \ x_2=(2+\tan t)\ x_1$

$ $

*edit*: With one more line, in an intermediate calculation you can can eliminate all six numbers:

```
 A = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
 MatrixExp[A t].{x1, x2} // FullSimplify

 % /. {a -> 1, b -> -1, c -> 5, d -> -3, x1 -> 1, x2 -> 2} // FullSimplify
```

Comment: You could also elect to use the two-argument form of `MatrixExp[]`: `MatrixExp[{{a, b}, {c, d}} t, {x1, x2}]`

Comment: @Nick Kidman I wonder how to solve this with your method if $x_1(0)=1$ and $x_2(0)=2$ is not given. You can't multiply Matrix A with to vectors of 0.

Comment: @JensJensen: "You can't multiply Matrix A with to vectors of 0." I'm not sure what you're saying, but if you say you can't use it for initial values $(0,0)$, then you're not right. Of course you can: $\text{e}^{At}\vec 0=\vec 0$. And this is exactly the solution of the differential equation: E.g $\dot x_1(0)=x_1(0)-x_2(0)=0$, then it says that the value starts at $x_1(0)=0$ and doesn't change.

Comment: @NickKidman What if $\dot{x_1} = \dot{x_2}(0)=0$ is given? And you only have the matrix A?

Comment: @JensJensen: I don't know what you're saying. You read off the matrix $A$ from the differential equation. You exponentiate it. You multiply the resulting matrix $\text{e}^{A t}$ with the initial vector. Now matter what the matrix or the differential equations are, this works. If the vector is $\vec 0$, then the vector will stay this $\vec 0$ no matter what the matrix is. If the matrix is four $0'$s, then $\text{e}^{A t}=E$, where $E$ is the unit matrix. No evolution as the differential equation given via $A$ is trivial. For any "What if" question like that, you can also just ask the code here.

Answer (score 5):

```
s = DSolve[{x'@t == x@t - y@t, y'@t == 5 x@t - 3 y@t, x@0 == 1, y@0 == 2}, {x, y}, t]
ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]} /. s, {t, 0, 5}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
Animate[Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[{x[t], y[t]} /. s]}, 
                  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-2, 2}}, Axes -> True], {t, 0, 10, .01}]
```

[image]